# AWS iOS SDK Get bucket metadata

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, amazon-s3

I see that there is an S3GetObjectMetaDataRequest, but is there some way to get the meta data of all objects in the bucket? I've checked S3ObjectSummary and it doesn't have any meta data.

Answer (score 0):

To get information about objects in a bucket through the API you will have to iterate through a list of enumerated objects, i.e. you have to get a list of the objects and then individually make calls for each object you want information on, i.e. there's no way to say something like "gimme an array with metadata for all objects". I learned this after hours of working with S3 object versioning.

Comment: That would be an awfully lot of requests. I've checked S3 object versioning but it only returns the standard meta data, and not custom ones. Looks like I have to resort to other solutions and use external db to manage this.

Comment: Requests are the single biggest detractor about S3. If AWS *quadrupled* the number of requests per penny, it would still make me grimace.